# Where does the quote “If you live each day as if it was your last, someday you'll most certainly be right” come from?

Tags: quote-source

The quote "If you live each day as if it was your last, someday you'll most certainly be right" is often attributed to Steve Jobs, but a quote posted on [LibQuotes](https://libquotes.com/steve-jobs/quote/lbo5d1e) suggests that Steve Jobs was himself quoting someone else:

> When I was 17, I read a quote that went something like: "If you live each day as if it was your last, someday you'll most certainly be right."

I tried Googling, but there are too many sites that simply attribute the quote to Steve Jobs

Is  LibQuotes.com misquoting Steve Jobs? If not, who is Steve Jobs quoting?

Comment: [Wikiquote notes](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Steve_Jobs#Address_at_Stanford_University_(2005)) an earlier occurrence in the film *Breaker Morant* (1980): "Live every day as if it were going to be your last. One day, you're sure to be right." (The film was adapted from a 1978 play by Kenneth Ross, so the line might be further traceable to the play.)

Comment: Also attributed online to [Kenneth G. Ross](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/507735-live-each-day-as-if-it-were-your-last-for), [Benny Hill](https://quotecatalog.com/quote/benny-hill-live-each-day-a-baV3Wb1), [MF Grimm](https://www.quotemaster.org/qa4a9184a9ab821d9452c3288bc791311), [Malachy McCourt](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/malachy_mccourt_575162), [Frank Sinatra](https://thatsthespir.it/of/frank-sinatra/live-every-day-like-its-your-last-one-day-youll-be-right).

Comment: I think asking this question on skeptics SE was a better idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steve Jobs may have misremembered a quote from [Andrew Sinclair's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Sinclair) 1964 novel *The Raker*, from which Google Books gives the following [snippet](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22if+you+live+each+day+as+if+it%22+%22your+last%22&biw=1920&bih=901&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1700%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1980&tbm=bks):

> If you live each day as if it were your last, Death is hardly unexpected when he calls.

The wording is not identical, but the idea is very similar. [Steve Jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Jobs) turned 17 in 1972, eight years after the novel's publication. By the time of the [2005 commencement address at Stanford](https://news.stanford.edu/news/2005/june15/jobs-061505.html), he was 50, which is more than enough time for a memory to get distorted.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite the quote you are looking for, but perhaps an early basis/inspiration for it:

> We learnt elsewhere, R. Eliezer said: Repent one day before your death. His disciples asked him, Does then one know on what day he will die? Then all the more reason that he repent to-day, he replied, lest he die to-morrow, and thus his whole life is spent in repentance.
>
> <sup>(Babylonian Talmud, Tractate Shabbat, folio 153a, [Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/shabbath/shabbath_153.html))</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Roman Emporer Marcus Aurelius c. 121 - 180 AD:
“Perfection of character is this: to live each day as if it was your last, without frenzy, without apathy and without pretence.”

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, this doesn't seem to match the "you'll be right one day" part of the quote.

Comment: Did he say "If you live each day as if it was your last, **someday you'll most certainly be right**"?

Comment: To the downvoters and critics of this answer: considering that real quotes from known authors are often distorted into something else, claiming that this is "not an answer" seems unduly harsh.

Comment: My problem with this answer is that if the quote in the question has two ideas - A ("live each day like it's your last") and B ("you'll be right someday") - then the proposed original quote lacks one idea and inserts a different one. It has A and C ("without X etc.") but lacks B, which seems to be a central part of the previous. While quotes can be distorted through word-of-mouth, that's true, this seems an awfully far distance from what's being asked.

Comment: Hi Andrew, with all this debate about your answer I see we haven’t got around to welcoming you as a new user. Welcome to Literature SE! You’ll have noticed that we take answers pretty seriously so taking a few minutes to go on our [tour] should help you understand expectations. You can also pop by the [chat] or look things up/ask questions on [meta] if you need more assistance. If this answer doesn’t do well, don’t worry, we have plenty more for you to try.